# ImportError: No module named 'tensorrt' in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, tensorrt

I installed tensorrt
But got :

> ImportError: No module named 'tensorrt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip3 install tensorrt-<version>-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

It can be found under **home/TensorRT-version /python** after you extract your .tar file.

and add TensorRT to the path.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/path_to_tensorrt/lib"
```

Comment: Where to put this line: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/path_to_tensorrt/lib"